# how to stop additional bone and bone chains in the fbx file export

Tags: rigging

[image]"how to stop additional bone and bone chains in the fbx file export" , my fbx export files always have multiple bone additions in the exported fbx file, so how do I prevent this from happening in 2.79b ?

[image]

after export pic (1)
Before export pic (2)

Answer (score 1):

In the export options deselect "Add Leaf Bones" This option creates bones that are connected to the heads and tails of the bones you've created in your blender native rig.

[image]

This image shows the default options.